# Raising WPF MouseLeftButtonDownEvent event programmatically

Tags: wpf, events, raise

I am trying to raise a MouseLeftButtonDownEvent by bubbling it up the Visual tree
with the following code.

```cs
var args = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice,0,MouseButton.Left);
args.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent;
args.Source = this;
RaiseEvent(args);
```

For some reason the higher level components are not receiving this bubbled event.
Am I overlooking something or is it not possible to raise this Mouse event

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your problem is that you are raising an event that does not bubble.

`MouseLeftButtonDownEvent` is defined as `RoutingStrategy.Direct`, which means it is routed to only the control receiving the event.

You want to use `Mouse.MouseDownEvent` event instead.  `UIElement` and other classes internally convert this into a `MouseLeftButtonDownEvent`.  Make sure you set e.ChangedButton to `MouseButton.Left`:

```
RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left)
{
  RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseDownEvent,
  Source = this,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong in my opinion - but at least I looked some time ago for quite some length into `InputManager`.

My resume from that is: The bubbling and tunneling is done by `InputManager`. However calling `uielement.Raise()` will only ever deliver the event directly (regardless of the `RoutingStrategy` as Ray Burns mentioed).

But (guessing) depending on `RoutingStrategy` the `InputManager` goes up and down the visual tree between `CompositionRoot` and the `VisualTreeHlper.Hittest()-`ed Visual and delivers tunneling and bublling events.

There is a way to raise Events via the InputManager, but it is not official and needs reflection (I have it from another Stackoverflow post):

```
    void RaiseMouseInputReportEvent(Visual eventSource, int timestamp, int pointX, int pointY, int wheel)
    {
        Assembly targetAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(InputEventArgs));
        Type mouseInputReportType = targetAssembly.GetType("System.Windows.Input.RawMouseInputReport");

        Object mouseInputReport = mouseInputReportType.GetConstructors()[0].Invoke(new Object[] {
        InputMode.Foreground, timestamp, PresentationSource.FromVisual(eventSource),
        RawMouseActions.AbsoluteMove | RawMouseActions.Activate,
        pointX, pointY, wheel, IntPtr.Zero });

        mouseInputReportType.GetField("_isSynchronize", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .SetValue(mouseInputReport, true);

        InputEventArgs inputReportEventArgs = (InputEventArgs)targetAssembly
            .GetType("System.Windows.Input.InputReportEventArgs")
            .GetConstructors()[0]
            .Invoke(new Object[] {
            Mouse.PrimaryDevice,
            mouseInputReport });

        inputReportEventArgs.RoutedEvent = (RoutedEvent)typeof(InputManager)
            .GetField("PreviewInputReportEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
            .GetValue(null);

        bool handled = InputManager.Current.ProcessInput((InputEventArgs)inputReportEventArgs);
    }
```