# How to simulate a right click on datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, datagrid, simulation

I want to simulate a right click on datagrid in WPF, and a context menu pop up.
But I found that the context menu is popped up via the PopupControlService which is internal to MS and I cannot access. Now I have the datagrid instance. How can I simulate a right click on this datagrid?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGrid.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ContextMenuOpeningEvent));
```

Have you tried it?

Or

```
 DataGrid.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MouseRightButtonDownEvent));
```

Look here: https://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/wpf-simulate-mouse-click-in-code-behind/

And also here: [Raising WPF MouseLeftButtonDownEvent event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421304/raising-wpf-mouseleftbuttondownevent-event)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. But I had tried these two ways. Both didn't work. For the first one it complained that "System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuEventArgs'." And the second one: "System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs'"

Answer (score 0):

To by-passe the problem you can create manually the context menu and show it in the code behind ?

Comment: The context menu is ready, I am writing code to auto-test our context menu behavior.